# Как получить верхнее окно системы Windows?

Tags: winapi, delphi

Как можно получить текущее верхнее окно системы?

Но не активное или имеющее фокус, а именно верхнее.

Например, установленное с помощью API-функции `SetWindowPos` со вторым параметром `HWND_TOPMOST`.

Comment: слабо себе представляю как это будет работать. А если 2 окна выставят себя так ? Критерий не четкий.

Comment: Тогда одно окно опустится на уровень ниже, а другое станет верхним =) Надо бы вам подучить...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `GetForegroundWindow`, чтобы получить активное окно, и функцию `GetTopWindow` (указав родительским окном `0` (desktop)), либо функцию `GetWindow` с параметром `GW_HWNDFIRST`, чтобы получить верхнее окно.

Comment: GetWindow(NULL,GW_HWNDFIRST); возвращает 0

GetTopWindow(NULL); похоже возвращает хэндл верхнего элемента управления

GetForegroundWindow(NULL); возвращает активное (имеющее фокус) окно (даже если оно находится ниже всех, например рабочий стол)

Comment: GetTopWindow(NULL) - ошибка! Не работает...

Comment: У меня тоже в Delphi ошибку выдает, а на Си нет.

Comment: Хоть, вероятно, уже все сроки вышли, все же напишу. Разумеется, `NULL` в Delphi выдаст ошибку, ведь это сишный макрос. Надо писать `0`.